# Testing real back end service with Angular 2 and Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I would like do some basic end to end testing between a test instance of my rails backend api an my Angular2 app. (that I am just starting).

I created the app with the cli and a service (also with the cli).
I added a method to the service to attempt to make a request and a spec to test it but I can see in the console for the Krama browser window the request is not going to the ip I would like it to go to, rather is is going to what appears to be the karma "server".

Is there any way I can direct http requests to a specific ip when using this setup?

### The service I would like to test

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class RailsBackendService {

  private mainToken = "some_api_access_token";
  private tokenQueryKey = "api_access_token";

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  get token(): string {
    return this.mainToken;
  }

  getUserList() : Observable<any> {
    console.log("getting user list");
    const querySting = `${this.tokenQueryKey}=${this.token}`;
    const requestURL = `http:172.16.1.114/api/v1/users/?${querySting}`;
    this.http.get(requestURL).subscribe();
    return this.http.get(requestURL);
  }

}
```

### The spec

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { RailsBackendService } from './rails-backend.service';
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';

describe('RailsBackendService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [RailsBackendService]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([RailsBackendService], (service: RailsBackendService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should exist', inject([RailsBackendService], (service: RailsBackendService) => {
    console.log('here2');
    expect(service.getUserList().subscribe( 
      (x) => {console.log("next",x);},
      (x) => {console.log("error triggered",x, "error done");},
      () => {console.log("complete",x);}
      )).toBe('x');
    }
  ));
});
```

### The console response

Note the localhost:9876 in front of the desired ip address.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious reason for web app to treat the specified URL as relative and concatenate it to current base URL in the request is that the protocol wasn't specified.

Indeed, it is malformed:

```
const requestURL = `http:172.16.1.114/api/v1/users/?${querySting}`;
```

It should be `http://...`.